# Remove DLL from system32 folder when uninstalling a setup from InstallScript project for 64-bit

Tags: dll, 64-bit, installshield, system32, syswow64

I have InstallShield 2011 and I am creating a setup for 64-bit in an InstallScript project.

When I install a setup, the DLL does go into system32 folder on a 64-bit system. But the problem is that when I unintall the setup, the DLL in system32 is not deleted.

If I copy the DLL in SYSWOW64 folder and uninstall the setup, the DLL is removed from the SYSWOW64 folder but not from systen32.

Comment: Your setup program is likely 32-bit, which means that file system redirection is kicking in and causing `system32` to be redirected to `syswow64`, and therefore removing the wrong DLL.

Comment: I am using szSDKDirectory=PROGRAMFILES64 and Disable(WOW64FSREDIRECTION)

Comment: FWIW, it's a Microsoft best practice to mark all components in the SYSTEMFOLDER as permenant.

Comment: @Christopher: [citation needed]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368933(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This all goes back to the days of DLL hell.  In general one should first avoid deploying to system folder in the first place and if it must be done it should be left for ever to make sure you don't break other applications on uninstall.

Comment: @Christopher: Ah, thanks. Yes, agreed about *not* deploying in the system folder. That's really the most important point here. It's named "System" for a reason. Too many developers seem to forget that they're *not* the system.

Comment: Is it possible to regsvr32 a 32bit DLL from outside of SYSWOW64?